# Как заполнить текстовый массив ключами HashMap? Java

Tags: java, массивы, key, hashmap

У меня есть карта с названем "CartoonCollection", ключи все которого — являются названиями популярных мультфильмов:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> CartoonCollection = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
hashMap.put("History of toys", 5); //Значения — рандомные числа, они не важны
hashMap.put("Lion king", 8);
hashMap.put("Spirited Away", 12);
hashMap.put("The beauty and the Beast", 5);
hashMap.put("Bambi", 9);
hashMap.put("Snow White and the 7 Dwarfs", 2)
```

Я хочу создать массив, где будут хранится все ключи CartoonCollection:

`String[] massive = new String[6];`

И вот, что мне удалось написать:

```
for (int i = 0; i<6; i++) {
            for (String key : Cartoon.CartoonCollection.keySet()) {
                massive[i] = key;         
    } 
}
```

Когда я вывожу "massive" на консоль, то результат таков:

```
for (int j = 0; j<massive.length; j++) {
System.out.println(massive[j]);
}

|Output|
Snow White and the 7 Dwarfs
Snow White and the 7 Dwarfs
Snow White and the 7 Dwarfs
Snow White and the 7 Dwarfs
Snow White and the 7 Dwarfs
Snow White and the 7 Dwarfs
```

**Что я делаю не так?**

Comment: во внутреннем цикле по ключам коллекции, Вы текущему элементу массива поочерёдно присваиваете все значения ключей. А по завершении цикла там естественным образом остаётся последнее значение "Snow White and the 7 Dwarfs"

Comment: `String[] massive = Cartoon.CartoonCollection.keySet().toArray()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть более интересные способы создать массив, не путаясь в циклах

```
String[] massive = Cartoon.CartoonCollection.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
```

или так, чтобы не создавать лишний массив-образец

```
Set<String> cartoonKeys = Cartoon.CartoonCollection.keySet();
String[] massive = cartoonKeys.toArray(new String[cartoonKeys.size()]);
```

или так

```
String[] massive = Cartoon.CartoonCollection.keySet().stream()
                                                     .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 0;
//for (int i = 0; i<6; i++) {
    for (String key : Cartoon.CartoonCollection.keySet()) {
        massive[i++] = key;         
    } 
//}
```